# Select with more condition similar in Orientdb

Tags: select, conditional-statements, orientdb

I have a table is user. This table has 5 user with id is 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 and 5.

Now, i want select users with id 1 , 3 and 5.

I wrote : `select from user WHERE id = '1' or id= '3' or id ='5'`.  It is ok.

But if i have more user I cant wrote such . because it is very long.

I dont want use **for** to  select it.

I was try with **IN** such as mysql . But it notice error.

Who can help me this situation ?

Comment: `WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)`?

Comment: No. it notice error.

I just discover must write like : Where id IN ['1','3','5']

Thanks

Comment: ok, i thought `ID` is `INT`. hmm, why are you saving it as string?

Comment: @Hyeongsik If you have discovered a solution to your problem, please submit it as an answer.